# How to view a <filename>.css.aspx file as if it were a *.css file in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, file-association

We have a web application C# / .Net based. The files for an individual website are saved as .ascx. Additionally, the associated CSS files are .css.aspx. Visual Studio displays these .css.aspx files as if they were XHTML 1.0 files. However, I'd love to be able to view them as if they were a normal .css file. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `.cs` files, as in C# files? I'm a little confused because `.css` usually is the extension used for Cascading Stylesheet files. Also, I think you may mean `<filename>.aspx.cs`?

Comment: No, they are set up as <filename>.css.aspx.

Comment: This problem might not be something that can be helped. It looks like the reason our files are setup as *.css.aspx is due to custom tags within the CSS code. When VS sees the file as a CSS file and compiles it as such, the build breaks because it doesn't know what our custom stuff is. This problem was a nice-to-have. So its not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your naming scheme to filename.aspx.css to view them as cascading style sheets.

Comment: I actually tried that. Problem is we have some custom tags we use and when VS compiles the *.css.aspx files as a .css, the build breaks cause it doesn't know what our custom tags are.